# Why doesn't this plot have a value of 14 at (0,0)?

Tags: matlab

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:0.5:10, -10:.5:10);
Z = 21*X^2 -34*X +  56*X*Y + 38*Y^2 -46*Y +14 ;
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

[image]

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html

I followed the procedure here but my plot has a value of 80,000 when I'd expect it to have a value of 14. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Matrix Multiplication vs Element-Wise Defined Surfaces

Have a feeling your aiming to do element-wise multiplication, instead of
matrix multiplication. Element-wise multiplication is indicated by the dot, `.` preceding the multiplication, `*` to form `.*`. If you don't specify element-wise multiplication MATLAB performs matrix multiplication. Element-wise multiplication multiplies the corresponding elements while matrix multiplication follows the form of indicated by: [MATLAB Documentation: Matrix Multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html). The result of the second subplot does indeed have a value of 14 which is ensured by using the `find()` function on the `Z`-surface to check.

[image: Matrix Multiplication vs Element-Wise Multiplication]

```
%Matrix multiplication%
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:0.5:10, -10:.5:10);
Z = 21*X^2 -34*X +  56*X*Y + 38*Y^2 -46*Y +14 ;
subplot(1,2,1); surf(X,Y,Z);
title("Matrix Multiplication Surface");
view(45,45);

%Element-wise multiplication%
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:0.5:10,-10:0.5:10);
Z = 21.*X.^2 -34.*X +  56.*X.*Y + 38.*Y.^2 - 46.*Y + 14 ;
subplot(1,2,2); surf(X,Y,Z);
title("Element-wise Multiplication Surface Z = f(X,Y)");
xlabel("X"); ylabel("Y")
[Row,Column] = find(Z == 14);
Z(Row,Column)
view(45,45);
```

---

The affects of matrix multiplication can be seen by the term `56*X*Y`. This results in a 41 by 41 double matrix filled with the value 80360.

```
56*X*Y
```

[image: Matrix Multiplication Result]

Comment: Updated the script forgot to add one `.`.